# Refresh WebView from Nav Button in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to add a refresh button to the top NavigationBar `StackNavigator` So I create a static property in the class `TheClass` like this

```
static headerRight = <Text onPress={() => this.onPress(this.state.url)}>Referesh</Text>;
```

So that I can access it from another file like this

> TheClass.headerRight

And my function is defined like this inside the same class

```
onPress = (url) => {
  this.setState({ url });
};
```

But I get an error

> Cannot read property 'onPress' of undefined

If I change the onPress to inline function it works

```
static headerRight = <Text onPress={() => console.log('Refresh tapped')}>Refresh</Text>;
```

Below is the full code of `TheClass.js`

```
'use strict';

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  WebView
} from 'react-native';

export default class TheClass extends Component<{}> {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      url: 'https://www.google.com'
    };
  };

  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Example',
  };

  onPress = (url) => {
    this.setState({ url });
  };

  static headerRight = <Text onPress={() => this.onPress(this.state.url)}>Refresh</Text>;

  render() {
    return (
      <WebView
        source={{uri: this.state.url}}
      />
    );
  }
}
```